# Message concatenation in MobileConnect SMS messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I've noticed that when sending messages longer than 160 characters from MobileConnect, it doesn't concatenate the messages when they are received on the handset. We've tried on different handsets and mobile networks but get the same result each time.

I also note that other SMS gateway providers support concatenation — that is the message appears as one long message when received on the handset.

Is this a known limitation in MobileConnect and if so, is there a workaround? We need to send approx 2.5m SMS messages annually for this campaign and I'd really like to use MobileConnect if we can...

[image: concatenation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a ticket on 3Sixty and received the following response to my case:

> Our Mobile Product team has advised that message concatenation support
>   for our Australian aggregator is planned for the first quarter of
>   2015.

Answer (score 1):

What numbers and countries are you sending a text message to?  We use several aggregators depending on the country we are supporting.  Some aggregators do not support concatenation while others do.

Comment: We're just using Australia (country code: 61). Is concatenation supported by your Australia aggregators?